# Filter Function Not Working in Live Servier

Tags: laravel, cpanel, laravel-5.8

I have two table one is `categories` where have `parent_id` and another is `pages` where store `category id` in `category_id` column. i'm get `pages` where `category` `parent_id` is `0` using `filter` method. it's work fine on local host but in live server it's not working.

```
$pages = Page::with('category')->latest()->get()->filter(function($page){
            return $page->category->parent_id === 0;
         });
return view('admin.page',compact('pages'));
```

Comment: Please can you add some details? "it's not working" is a bit broad, what you get?

Comment: simply i'm just get all pages where category parent_id equal 0. my all pages have category id and few categories have children categories. i'm just want to get pages where category have no any child category

Comment: "simply i'm just get all pages where category parent_id equal 0." are you getting what you want or not? Please can you edit your question adding a sample of your actual result and of the expected result.

Comment: now actual result is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it without comparison:

```
$pages = Page::with('category')->latest()->get()->filter(function($page){
        return $page->category->parent_id;
     });

return view('admin.page',compact('pages'));
```